# find a holomorphic function such that: $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=0,\forall a\in\partial U$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subsetneq\mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $p\in U$. There is a holomorphic function$$f:U-\{p\}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$$ such that $$\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=0,\forall a\in\partial U$$ and $$\lim_{z\to p}f(z)=\infty\;?$$
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $p\in U$ or on the boundary?

Comment: the point $p\in U$

Comment: Then why did you write $\partial U \setminus \{p\}?$

Comment: Correction: $\forall a\in\partial U$.

Comment: Your second limit doesn't make any sense

Comment: Correction: $\lim_{z\to p}f(z)=\infty$

Comment: For $U$ something like the unit disc, the answer is no. But for some domains $U$ with small boundary, like $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\},$ the answer is yes.